# Python regex function to count repetitions of substring or divide a substring?

Tags: python, regex, string, dictionary, substring

I'm hoping you can help point me in the right direction as I'm very new to programming and Python in particular. I'm trying to find maximum repeat counts of certain substrings in a larger string. For example, how many times does `'AGATC'` repeat in a much longer string (it might appear only at one place but four times in a row at another place).

I've been reading up on regex for this and have written the code below. It will successfully print out repetitions for each pattern seperately, however, I need to know the repetition count for when it appears. Example output of my code looks like this:

```
['AGATCAGATCAGATCAGATC', 'TATCTATCTATCTATCTATC', 'GAAA', 'GATA', 'AATG', 'GAAA', 'GAAA', 'GATA']
```

In which case `'AGATC'` appears four times but `'TATC'` repeats five times, so I need this as an integer. If someone please has any ideas to move me forward I'd be deeply grateful.

Here is my full code:

```
import re

# Opens the textfile and stores it as a string
with open('STR.txt') as strfile: 
    for row in strfile:
        STRs = row

# Defines patterns we are searching for in STR
pattern1 = (r'(?:AGATC)+')
pattern2 = (r'(?:TTTTTTCT)+')
pattern3 = (r'(?:AATG)+')
pattern4 = (r'(?:TCTAG)+')
pattern5 = (r'(?:GATA)+')
pattern6 = (r'(?:TATC)+')
pattern7 = (r'(?:GAAA)+')
pattern8 = (r'(?:TCTG)+')

# Recompiles all patterns into one single pattern
mainpattern = re.compile("(%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s)" % (pattern1, pattern2, pattern3, pattern4, pattern5, pattern6, pattern7, pattern8))

# Finds the pattern matches in STR
STR_match = re.findall(mainpattern, STRs)

print(STR_match)
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you don't want the repeated strings (like 'AGATCAGATCAGATCAGATC', but instead 4 single matches) which you can then count. If that is true, you just have to remove the "+" from your search pattern and check the length of the result list.

Comment: Kind of, what I need is to count the amount of repeats In the case of 'AGATCAGATCAGATCAGATC' that would correspond to 4, but if AGATC appears in another place in the string I would get 5 and that would be incorrect as I need to count the maximum number of repeats at any position in the string.

Unfortunately I think removing the + then could yield incorrect results?

Comment: Ah, so you want want the maximum number of consecutive repeats of any of the patterns? E.g. in your example 5 for the `TATC...` part?

Comment: Exactly, that's what I'm trying to figure out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you could do this separately for each pattern, e.g. something like:

```py
patterns = ('AGATC', 'TTTTTTCT', 'AATG', 'TCTAG', ...)
max_len = 0
max_pattern = None
for pattern in patterns:
    match = re.findall(f'(?:{pattern})+', STRs)
    if match:
        longest = sorted(match)[-1]  # last is the longest match
        l = len(longest)/len(pattern)
        if l > max_len:
            max_len = l
            max_pattern = pattern
print(f"{max_len} x {max_pattern}")
```

This matching will return a list of all consecutive matching strings, and if you sort them alphabetically, the longest string will always be the last one, as they repeat the pattern. Then you can calculate the number of pattern repeats in that string.
If you just need the longest repeat, you can calculate the maximum of these numbers as shown.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to return a correct number (and I do understand the logic behind it I think). I've now trying to modify the code to print what pattern it was that was discovered that many times, for example, 'AGATC' was the one discovered 4 times.

Comment: I adapted the code. If you need all patterns with the max length, you have to modify it a bit, but that you can probably figure out yourself.

Comment: Thank you so much! I figured out this version (I changed the name of some variables):
STR_name = longest[:int(len(longest)/STR_max)]

You really made my day by helping me, I really appreciate it.